# Variadically templated struct / How boost::variant is implemented

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, c++14

Is it possible to achieve an effect like the following

```
DifferentTypesInOne<string, int, double> variant_obj;
```

Where you `variant_obj` has variables of types string, int and double in it.

I know this is similar to `boost::variant`.  And I searched up questions about it before but I was not able to stumble upon an explanation which could explain how the class uses variadic templates to store elements of all the types.  In particular I am asking how I can go about defining a `struct` which has variables of all the given types and a member variable denoting which one is important currently.

Thanks!

Comment: For a variant, either recursion with unions, or you have a piece of storage and use placement new.

Comment: I am just having a hard time understanding how I can have lots of elements of the types included in a variadic template list inside a struct

Comment: Does that comment make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly,

```
template<class... Ts> 
struct variant_storage {};

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct variant_storage<T, Ts...>{
    union {
        T head;
        variant_storage<Ts...> tail;
    };
};

template<class... Ts>
struct variant {
    int index;
    variant_storage<Ts...> storage;
};
```

This is a sketch; for details [these](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-17/eggs.variant---part-i) [articles](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-20/eggs.variant---part-ii-the-constexpr-experience) are a good read.

If you don't need `constexpr`-ness, you can store a `std::aligned_union_t<0, Ts...>` as storage, and use placement new, which is simpler.

Comment: Whoa this is awesome.  Could you explain what exactly is happening here?

Comment: @Curious: It's recursion, a basic tool of template metaprogramming (and programming in general).

Comment: Wait it isn't recursion.  It's compile time recursion which isn't real recursion right?

Comment: @Curious what is "real" here?

Comment: @Orient Stack over stack over stack?

Comment: @Curious Yeah, stack of the compiler's parsing functions during compile time.

Comment: @Orient  Since we did not specify a compiler here, who knows, the compiler may do it manually without using recursion for it's own functions.

Comment: @Curious Also we don't know how compiled that compiler. Maybe host compiler unrolls loops up to 1024 template nesting depth or reduces tail recursion for mentioned functions...

Comment: @Orient ok.. Let us both just wait for the new Game of Thrones season to come out now

Answer (score 1):

C++11 provided a template type, [`std::aligned_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union), which takes a list of types. `aligned_union::type` is a type which has sufficient storage space and alignment to be the storage for any of those given types.

So that's how you create the storage for the data. All you need beyond that is an integer that tells which value is stored there.

```
template<typename ...Types>
struct variant
{
private:
  uint8_t index;
  typename std::aligned_union<Types...>::type storage;
};
```

You use placement `new` to allocate the individual elements to a particular type, within the storage provided by `storage`.

Comment: How would you match the type with an index?

Comment: Wait how would you match the type with an index?